# IllegalIllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: java, android, view, parent-child

so I got this error (just like 50,000 other people), and I've looked through their mistakes/answers, but still can't figure out how to resolve my issue. Can someone look through my code and tell me where the error is / how I should resolve it? Thanks.

Oh, and I'm new to coding so I don't know where the error is... Logcat doesn't tell me which line/fragment/class/whatever is causing the crash. I'm sorry for posting legit every line of code.

If someone wants to explain to me where in the world to look to find this error, that would be great also. Thanks, guys!

```
package com.e.whosin.Adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;
import com.e.whosin.CommentsActivity;
import com.e.whosin.FollowersActivity;
import com.e.whosin.Fragment.PostDetailFragment;
import com.e.whosin.Fragment.ProfileFragment;
import com.e.whosin.Model.Post;
import com.e.whosin.Model.User;
import com.e.whosin.R;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    public Context mContext;
    public List<Post> mPost;

    private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

    public PostAdapter(Context context, List<Post> post) {
        mContext = context;
        mPost = post;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.post_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new PostAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        final Post post = mPost.get(i);

        Glide.with(mContext).load(post.getPostimage())
                .apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.portraitplaceholder))
                .into(viewHolder.post_image);

        if (post.getDescription().equals("")){
            viewHolder.description.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            viewHolder.description.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewHolder.description.setText(post.getDescription());
        }

        publisherInfo(viewHolder.image_profile, viewHolder.username, viewHolder.publisher, post.getPublisher());
        isLikes(post.getPostid(), viewHolder.like);
        nrLikes(viewHolder.likes, post.getPostid());
        getComments(post.getPostid(), viewHolder.comments);
        isSaved(post.getPostid(), viewHolder.save);

        viewHolder.image_profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mContext.getSharedPreferences("PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString("profileid", post.getPublisher());
                editor.apply();

                ((FragmentActivity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new ProfileFragment()).commit();
            }
        });

        viewHolder.username.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mContext.getSharedPreferences("PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString("profileid", post.getPublisher());
                editor.apply();

                ((FragmentActivity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new ProfileFragment()).commit();
            }
        });

        viewHolder.publisher.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mContext.getSharedPreferences("PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString("profileid", post.getPublisher());
                editor.apply();

                ((FragmentActivity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new ProfileFragment()).commit();
            }
        });

        viewHolder.post_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mContext.getSharedPreferences("PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString("postid", post.getPostid());
                editor.apply();

                ((FragmentActivity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new PostDetailFragment()).commit();
            }
        });

        viewHolder.save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (viewHolder.save.getTag().equals("save")){
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Saves").child(firebaseUser.getUid())
                            .child(post.getPostid()).setValue(true);
                } else {
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Saves").child(firebaseUser.getUid())
                            .child(post.getPostid()).removeValue();
                }
            }
        });

        viewHolder.like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (viewHolder.like.getTag().equals("like")){
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes").child(post.getPostid())
                            .child(firebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(true);
                    addNotifications(post.getPublisher(), post.getPostid());
                } else {
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes").child(post.getPostid())
                            .child(firebaseUser.getUid()).removeValue();
                }
            }
        });

        viewHolder.comment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, CommentsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("postid", post.getPostid());
                intent.putExtra("publisherid", post.getPublisher());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        viewHolder.comments.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, CommentsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("postid", post.getPostid());
                intent.putExtra("publisherid", post.getPublisher());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        viewHolder.likes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, FollowersActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", post.getPostid());
                intent.putExtra("title", "likes");
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mPost.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public ImageView image_profile, post_image, like, comment, save;
        public TextView username, likes, publisher, description, comments;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            image_profile = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_profile);
            post_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
            like = itemView.findViewById(R.id.like);
            comment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment);
            save = itemView.findViewById(R.id.save);
            username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
            likes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.likes);
            publisher = itemView.findViewById(R.id.publisher);
            description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            comments = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comments);
        }
    }

    private void getComments(String postid, final TextView comments){
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Comments").child(postid);

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                comments.setText("View All "+dataSnapshot.getChildren() + " Comments");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    //To like posts and to show how many likes each post has
    private void isLikes(String postid, final ImageView imageView){

        final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("Likes")
                .child(postid);

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).exists()){
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_liked);
                    imageView.setTag("liked");
                } else {
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_like);
                    imageView.setTag("like");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void nrLikes (final TextView likes, String postid){
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes")
                .child(postid);
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                likes.setText(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()+" likes");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void publisherInfo(final ImageView image_profile, final TextView username, final TextView publisher, String userid){
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userid);

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                Glide.with(mContext).load(user.getImageurl()).into(image_profile);
                username.setText(user.getUsername());
                publisher.setText(user.getUsername());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void addNotifications(String userid, String postid){
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notifications").child(userid);

        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("userid", firebaseUser.getUid());
        hashMap.put("text", "liked your post");
        hashMap.put("postid", postid);
        hashMap.put("ispost", true);

        reference.push().setValue(hashMap);
    }

    private void isSaved(final String postid, final ImageView imageView){
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Saves")
                .child(firebaseUser.getUid());

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.child(postid).exists()){
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_save_black);
                    imageView.setTag("saved");
                } else {
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_save);
                    imageView.setTag("save");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.e.whosin, PID: 23744
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:5099)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4930)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4870)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4843)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)

```
package com.e.whosin.Fragment;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.e.whosin.Adapter.UserAdapter;
import com.e.whosin.Model.User;
import com.e.whosin.R;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private UserAdapter userAdapter;
    private List<User> mUsers;

    EditText search_bar;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, true);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        search_bar = view.findViewById(R.id.search_bar);

        mUsers = new ArrayList<>();
        userAdapter = new UserAdapter(getContext(), mUsers, false);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);

        readUsers();
        search_bar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                searchUsers(charSequence.toString().toLowerCase());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void searchUsers(String s){
        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").orderByChild("username")
                .startAt(s)
                .endAt(s+"\uf8ff");

        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mUsers.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    mUsers.add(user);
                }

                userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void readUsers(){

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (search_bar.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    mUsers.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                        mUsers.add(user);
                    }

                    userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Saw that some people posted their xml file. If that's needed to get to the bottom of this, let me know!

Comment: any fragment you are using ?

Comment: @Swayangjit yeah man, there are two I suppose that could be the issue. I'll post them at the bottom for you. PostDetailFragment, ProfileFragment

Comment: Please use Pastebin to post you, classes , don't clutter the post.

Comment: @Swayangjit damn, wish I knew about Pastebin sooner... Anyways, below you have the PostDetailFragment I'm using. You think that's the fragment causing the crash?

Comment: @Swayangjit and the ProfileFragment below it

Comment: BTW When it's crashing?

Comment: @Swayangjit HomeActivity is fine, and then I click on an icon in the bottom navigation bar and it crashes and the error comes up 'The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first'. Usually it tells me in blue which line is causing the error, but this time it isn't

Comment: Then there is some issue with bottom navigation flow

Comment: @Swayangjit yeah, I just have no idea what to do about it. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @Swayangjit hey, do you mind looking it it one more time? The crash occurs ONLY when I hit the SearchFragment, all the other ones navigate to their respective fragments. I posted the SearchFragment up top!

Comment: About using pastebin: please share all the code necessary to reproduce the problem *in your question*.  Links to other sources may be broken in the future. So without the relevant code snippets your question may be considered ["off topic"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

So I've been playing around with it and got to the solution to my problem which was changing attachToRoot from True to False in the SearchFragment... Can someone explain why that is though?